# Why is my conditional execution in my aspx page not returning the correct result?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have ASP.Net(aspx) where I need to render the html based on some condition. This is how my aspx looks like.

```
<%# Eval("FileName").ToString()  == "pdf" ?"True":"False"%>
```

This is returning string True or False based on the condition however I need to render the html as below.

```
<%# Eval("FileName").ToString()  == "pdf" ?"":"<img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 'FilePathUrl')%>' />"%>
```

How do I address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the string for the image like this:

```
<%# Eval("FileName").ToString() == "pdf" ? "" : "<img src=\"" + Eval("FilePathUrl").ToString() + "\">" %>
```

You cannot nest databinding expressions like you are doing.

Comment: Thanks!! Please upvote the post if you think its worth

Answer (score 0):

You can use "if" statement instead of "?:"

```
<% if (Eval("FileName").ToString() != "pdf")%>
<% { %>
    <img src='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, 'FilePathUrl')%>
<% } %>
```